# Position Element Directly Below Navigation Bar (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to figure out how to position a Rectangle() just below the navigation bar (there should be no space between these two elements). So far the only solution I have found is to guess the height of the navigation bar and offset the Rectangle() by that amount. Is there any way to get the height of the navigation bar programmatically or to pin an element directly under the navigation bar. I need a solution which allows me to adapt the position of my Rectangle() based on screen size. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: the NavigationBar has the height of the safe area. Hence, if you have configured your view with the modifier .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) UIElements can render beneath the Navigation Bar. My fix came by removing the edgesIgnoringSafeArea modifier from the outermost ZStack which prevented the rectangle from appearing at a y-value less than the safe area height.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your parent view has no restrictions, use this code

```
YourRectangle()
   .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5)
```

This will put your view in the center

Comment: Hi Sergio, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I need the rectangle to appear at the BOTTOM of the navigation bar (there should be no space between these two items).